# how can remove a timer correctly in jquery?

Tags: jquery, timer, clearinterval

if user click on div1 close div will show and I want clear and remove timer when user click on close div, and call new timer when user click on div2, but newTimer() can't run when call again, and jquery stop all codes , how can clear and remove timer correctly?

HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="width:140px; height:140px; line-height:140px; text-align:center; font-size:24px; background-color:rgba(51,153,204,.5);">
  Click 1
</div>

<div id="div2" style="width:140px; height:140px; line-height:140px; text-align:center; font-size:24px; background-color:rgba(21,113,214,.5);">
  Click 2
</div>


<div id="showClose" style="position: absolute; width: 440px; height: 140px; line-height: 140px; text-align: center; font-size: 24px; background-color: rgba(21,113,214,.5); left: 276px; top: 272px;">
  Close Win
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#showClose, #click2").hide()
var blnnewTimer = false;

var timeris = function myTimer(clockTime, inClockFunction) {
  var stopClock = false;
  var ChatClock = {
    totalSeconds: 0,
    start: function() {
      this.interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (!stopClock) {
          stopClock = inClockFunction();
        } else {
          ChatClock.pause();
        }
      }, clockTime);
    },
    pause: function() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      delete this.interval;
    }
  };
  ChatClock.start();
}

function newTimer() {
  blnnewTimer = false;
  var newTimerTime = 3000;
  var newTimerFunc = function() {
    alert(blnnewTimer)
    return blnnewTimer;
  }
  newTimer = new timeris(newTimerTime, newTimerFunc);
}


$("#div1,#showClose,#div2").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
  $(this).css("color", "rgba(102,102,102,1)");
})
$("#div1,#showClose,#div2").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "rgba(0,0,0,1)");
})

$("#div1").click(function() {
  newTimer()
  $("#showClose").show(800)

})
$("#div2").click(function() {

  newTimer()  // here will not run newTimer function and code will be broken
  $("#showClose").show(800)
})
$("#showClose").click(function() {
  blnnewTimer = true;
  $("#showClose").hide()
  if (!$("#click2").is("visible")) $("#click2").show()
})
```

Also the test codes is availabe here
https://jsfiddle.net/rymia/ch3emqyd/
thank you

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is alomst impossible to read and understand!

Comment: Thank you, I changed my question, i hope it's good

Comment: Still really hard to read.. saw a little into it tho, you have many missing semicolons (`;`) and i do not really understand why you use your code, it seems your problem - which i do not fully understand - can be solved way easier. Is it true you want to show your `#showClose` when you click `#div1`, on click of `#showClose` add `#div2`? What should happen next tho?

Comment: The aim of this codes is clear timer  when #showClose is clicked ,first timer stoped and  #div1 or #div2 run new timer again when clicked again , but the code can't run new timer

Comment: I am really unsure what you are trying to achieve but is it [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/ch3emqyd/1/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
newTimer = new timeris(newTimerTime, newTimerFunc);
```

This keyword `new` should not be used in this case since `new` is used to return an object instance from a function, which is also known as pseudo-classical inheritance. Nothing about the way this function is structured suggests that you want an object returned where you have access to it's properties and methods.

Instead simply executing `timeris(newTimerTime, newTimerFunc)` will give you the desired results.